# ionic infinite not getting called

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
$scope.loadNotification = function(page) {
    showLoader(true);
    NotificationService.getNotification(page).then(function(response) {
        showLoader(false);
        var data = response.data, notifications = data.notifications, nextPage = data.nextPage;         
        renderNotification(notifications, nextPage);
    }, function(error) {
        showLoader(false);
        $scope.pageMesssag = error;
        $scope.reloadNotificationBtn=true;
    });
}

$scope.loadNextPage = function() {
    $scope.loadNotification($scope.nextPage);
}

function renderNotification(notifications, nextPage) {
    $scope.nextPage = nextPage;
    if(nextPage === 0 && notifications.length === 0) {
        $scope.pageMesssag = Utils.prepareErrorMessage('', "No notifications so far.");
    } else if(nextPage !== 0 && nextPage === undefined){
        $scope.pageMesssag = Utils.prepareErrorMessage('', "No more notifications available.");
    }
    $scope.notifications.push.apply($scope.notifications, notifications);
    var slicedNotidications = $scope.notifications;
    if(slicedNotidications.length > PAGINATION_SIZE) {
        slicedNotidications = slicedNotidications.slice(0, PAGINATION_SIZE);
    }
    angular.forEach(notifications, function(value, key) {
        if(!value.read) {
            readNotifications.push(value.id);
        }
    });
    NotificationService.storeLatestNotificcations(slicedNotidications, nextPage);
    if(readNotifications.length > 0){
        markNotification(readNotifications);                
    }       
    console.log("---"+$scope.nextPage);
}
```

Here is my html code:

```
<ion-infinite-scroll ng-if='nextPage !== undefined' on-infinite="loadNextPage()" distance="10%"></ion-infinite-scroll>
```

`loadNextPage` is not getting called even when `nextPage` has some value

Answer (score 0):

it seems nextPage is undefined at the beginning that is why loadNextPage is not being called. you need to set $scope.nextPage to some value outside  the RenderNotification Function.

Comment: `console.log("---"+$scope.nextPage);` is printing some value